# Meaning of the error message `Extension not found'

Tags: python, grass-gis, add-ons

I am trying to install the extension `r.stream.order` and when I use `g.extension` to install the module, I get the following error (Linux).

```
Fetching <r.stream.order> from GRASS GIS Addons repository (be patient)...
svn: E170000: URL 'https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-
addons/trunk/grass7/raster/r.stream.order' doesn't exist
ERROR: GRASS Addons <r.stream.order> not found
```

I have browsed to the URL pointed out and I found that it indeed does not exist. So what is the workaround?

Comment: I'm running GRASS GIS 7.0.3, it might not be your case, but in my *%GISBASE/gui/wxpython/modules/extensions.py* file the `defaultUrl = 'http://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass-addons/grass7'` is set. You can try with the _svnurl=_ or _url=_ (for recent versions) option to set the same url. GRASS GIS version included in the body of the question would be welcome.

Comment: I can confirm your suggestion works on grass gis 7.8.5